# Bootstrap button block change alignment when stacked vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, alignment, media-queries

https://jsfiddle.net/wc3f1h0m/

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>                
            <div class="col-xs-10">

                <div class="btn-block">

                    <input style="max-width:170px;" type="submit" class="appBtn btn btn-primary" value="App Button One"
                    />
                    <input style="max-width:170px;" type="submit" class="appBtn btn btn-primary" 
                     value="App Button Two"

                    />
                </div>
            </div>                
        </div>
```

I have two button underneath a form in a btn-block. While the form is wide enough, I would like the buttons side by side (stacked horizontally), and roughly centered under the form.

When the screen width shrinks, eventually the buttons will stack vertically (due to btn-block), but at this point I would like to align them left, rather than their initial center position.

Currently I am just offsetting them using another column, so I would like that left column to dissapear when they stack vertically, or some other way of achieving this. I was thinking of having another  with a certain width but zero height, but when I tried that the div always stays to the left of the first button, it does not get stacked vertically alongside the others.

How can I center the buttons when they are stacked horizonally, but left align them when they switch vertically?

More generally, how can I apply rules based on this "switch" - do the elements get a different class when they switch to stacking vertically I can apply more rules on?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that you can make them automatically align left once they no longer fit side by side but you can if you define a particular media query break point for them to do that at. So because you've got a max-width on the buttons of 170px each, i've applied the media query to keep them left aligned up until 320px. Seems to hit the mark pretty well.

https://jsfiddle.net/wc3f1h0m/15/

key changes are:
1) get rid of the col-xs-1 div as the buttons are centered now anyway so its not doing anything.
2) adding a new class "btn-alignment" to the "btn-block" so that we can apply our own custom css to it.

```
.btn-block.btn-alignment {
  text-align:left;
}
@media(min-width:320px) {
  .btn-block.btn-alignment {
    text-align:center;
  }
}
```

Also changed your h5's to labels which is what you should use to define inputs on forms.

Comment: Thanks. How do I make this happen when the buttons switch from horizontal to vertical rather than at a fixed break point (link 320px)?

Comment: Hi @aaa90210 I really can't think of a way to make that happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">           
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Button One">
  </div>        
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Button Two">
  </div>
</div>
```

Or this inverse:

```
<div class="row">           
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Button One">
  </div>        
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Button Two">
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this the sort of thing you are looking for? Was kind of confused how the whole form was wrapped in a col-md-4 as to get the behaviour you were looking for. Hopefully one of these

Comment: I thought the "btn-block" meant I didn't need to put each button in its own column? I saw other examples like that.

Comment: btn-block is modifier that instructs the element to span the entire width of its parent - i added it for aesthetic value. if your looking for a bootstrap solution to layout your form, use the grid. otherwise, you are writing a new class for the purpose (using floats and media queries) - which is what the grid does anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
'<style type="text/css">
/*Use the following code*/
@media(max-width:320px) {
  .btn-block .appBtn{
    display:block;
    margin:10px auto;
  }
}

/*-----or---------*/

@media(max-width:480px) {
  .btn-block .appBtn{
    display:block;
    margin:10px auto;
  }
}
</style>'
```